# Css change style of unorderded list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have made a basic unordered list.

```
<ul>
<li><a>abc</a></li>
<li><a>def</a></li>
<li><a>ghi</a></li>
<li><a>jkl</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to style it so that it doesnt display the dots infront of the words I just want the words to be displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `list-style-type` for that:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Add the above to a CSS file and it won't have bullets in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the following css:

```
ul{
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `list-style` attribute:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```